# Error while importing registry entries in NSIS

Tags: windows, registry, nsis

I am making the wrapper for my application through NSIS setup. In the wrapper I need to do some registry entries for my application. The entries will be in the registry path “HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft” and “HKLM\SOFTWARE\ Microsoft”.

The problem is when I am importing the registry through the [ExecWait ”regedit.exe /s registry.reg”] command in the NSIS, the registry entry will not be added to the path “HKLM\SOFTWARE\ Microsoft”, only in other entry it will be added. And along with this in NSIS setup there will be a new entry in the path “HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Wow6432Node \Microsoft” which is come from nowhere, because I did not include any registry entry mentioned like that in the registry file.

I checked the registry file and there was no problem in it. I tried by directly running the registry file and also tried the same command directly in a bat file as well as CMD (regedit.exe /s registry.reg ). All are working fine. Only in NSIS it is not working. Any help would be great.

**EDIT**:
Operating system: windows 7, 64 Bit

NSIS version: 2.46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your application nsis installer is for 32bit.
Since it is a 32bit installer every registry operation is automatically converted by windows applying the compatibility key "Wow6432Node".
see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa384232(VS.85).aspx) about registry redirection

for switching between 32-bit and 64-bit registry your code should looks like:

```
SetRegView 64
WriteRegDWORD HKLM "SOFTWARE\<Key1>\<Key2>" "Value" 0
SetRegView 32
WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\<Key1>\<Key2>" "Value" "1"
```

since nsis has its own native functions for modifying the windows registry, using `ExecWait regedit.exe /s registry.reg` is not a good idea

Comment: I have a reg file for my registry entries. And yes i can use the default functions like WriteRegStr and SetRegView using the 'Reg2nsis' application to convert my reg file but the problem is, there is a bug in this converter application which give wrong registry values when converted. So i droped the option of using the default functions

Comment: if you are trying to convert a registry file that contains direct reference to Wow6432Node probably Reg2nsis will never work properly, you have to do it manually

Comment: you can try running C:\Windows\Syswow64\REGEDIT /s MYapp.reg

it is a pretty dirty solution and I am not sure if it will work properly

Comment: thank you for the reply. but ExecWait 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe /s "64 bit registry_final.reg"' not working...

Comment: try something like ExecWait cmd /c regedit.exe /s registry.reg (probably you have to add some " in the proper place)

Answer (score 1):

Just calling `Exec "regedit.exe"` from a 32-bit application will start 32-bit Regedit and that causes the Wow6432Node\Wow6432Node issue.

The real solution is to use [Reg2Nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reg2Nsis_-_convert_registry_info_into_NSIS_commands) or some other conversion tool to convert your .reg file into `WriteRegStr` and `SetRegView` instructions.

You can try running 64-bit Regedit with this ugly hack:

```
!include x64.nsh
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
ExecWait '"$WinDir\Regedit.exe" /whatever'
${EnableX64FSRedirection}
```

Comment: I don't know why "DisableX64FSRedirection" is not working as well as "RunningX64" also not working which is of x64.nsh.

Now the problem solved when i manually redirecting wherever required.